# Proof of infimum of a convex function being convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In Boyd's convex optimization book, he gave [this proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRBYy.png). I'm not sure how did he claim that

$f(x_i, y_i) \leq g(x_i) + \epsilon$

And how does it relate to Jensen's Inequality.

Comment: This answer may help https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4508793/27978